# postgresql Cannot login with created users

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to postgreSQL, but quite familiar with SQL.

I have recently installed postgreSQL on Windows 10.  I ran through the startup tutorials and made a few DBs to mess around with.  I can login just fine with the postgres account with the command

```
psql -U postgres -d DatabaseName
```

However, I have thus far been unable to create a new user to log in with.

I tried the command

```
CREATE USER myUser WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'password';
```

When I do this, it creates the user.  I can see this with the \du command:

```
Role name  |   List of Attributes                      | Member of
postgres   | Superuser, Create Role, Create DB, yada...| {}
myuser     | Superuser                                 | {}
```

I then try \q and logging in with my new user and get the following:

```
psql -U myUser -d Database
Password for myUser: password
psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for "myUser"
```

I have also tried createuser from cmd, this user showed up in the list of users as well, but I was again unable to login as these users.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Do you have entry for your host in `pg_hba.conf` with `md5` auth method?

Comment: Yes, it's in there.  The answer below solved my problem.  Thank you for your time!

Comment: I have the same issue today

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a case folding problem. You're trying to connect with `myUser` but due to case folding rules, you created `myuser` in lowercase, as the `\du` output shows. Per [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html):

> Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted
>   names are always folded to lower case.

To create `myUser` with this exact case, enclose it in double quotes, as in:

```
CREATE USER "myUser" WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'password';
```

Then the invocation `psql -U myUser ...` will work.

Or alternatively, don't recreate the user but always refer to it in lowercase.

Comment: I don't use upper-case username though I still failed; any idea what's wrong on my case @DanielVerite?

Comment: @NamGVU: if you don't use uppercase, please ask a new question, as it's not the same problem.